# Comparing images taken from Camera with already present images

Tags: iphone, ios, image-comparison

I am new to this platform.

I am developing application where I already have **100 images** previously stored and want to **compare** image which I take from **camera** and see it that image matched with from existing 100 images.

I searched a lot and found OpenCV framework, bit is doesn't seems to be helping me on this.

Any help on suggestion will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: an image will match only with self. if you have 2 images that differ just a little bit, the already do not match. of course your eyes can say "hey, it's almost the same image", but the computer cannot do that. instead you can find a technology to compare parts of the images, and, suppose if the computer says "pixels match %80-%90", well, it's a kind of match

Comment: I think this is a pretty good question actually.

Comment: @Danjah I dont know reason for closing this question that too after 6 months. Also, its quite strange that this question has been marked favorite by 6 people and still its closed stating as its not real question. Anyways, thanks for saying that..

Comment: A question been marked by 5 people as favorite and makes no sense for this question to be closed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV should be your best option. If you are looking for just image comparison, and just don't care about specific part of your image, then you can use [Histogram Comparison](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)

If you want to get in detail like objects, you can use feature detection and then comparing features. This method should be faster. However, I've read about combination of both methods like comparing feature points using histogram comparison.

Comment: +1 for good link and explanation